# How does one query SwiftUI table cells using XCUITest

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xcuitest

I am starting to include some SwiftUI code in my UIKit project. The UIKit project had UI Tests using `XCUITest` which, as you may know, can query elements down the UI tree and can even have an identifier to narrow do your elements found.

I have moved over all the accessibility identifiers, hints, labels, and values have been moved over to the SwiftUI components.

In my case, I had a `UITableView` which is now a SwiftUI `List`. In my UI tests, I would query the `UITableView` like this:

`let app = XCUIApplication()`

`let tableCells = app.table.cells["MyCellIdentifier"]`

However, while this worked in SwiftUI, it no longer works in SwiftUI's `List`. I understand SwiftUI pretty much hides more of the implementation details of how it builds its UI and it may not even be a Table View under the covers but it certainly looks and acts like the `UITableView` I was using before.

Does anyone know how to properly test a table view (List) in SwiftUI using `XCUITest` or why it doesn't work with the existing test code?

As you can see below, the sample code shows me adding a accessibility identifier to a `RowView` but for Accessibility, it gets passed down to the `Text` views (`StaticText` in the Accessibility tree).

[image]

Comment: This doesn’t sound right. There should be no difference in querying a table or cells built with SwiftUI. What does your `debugDescription` show?

Comment: @MikeCollins, good idea! I didn't think to try that so I just did. It's weird though. It seems to generate something different that what I'd expect based on how I combine elements. For example, the two Text labels I have in my "cell" have individual accessibility identifiers however they get erased because its containing VStack uses `.accessibilityElement(children: .combine)`. Also, there doesn't seem to be a way to add an identifier to the container cell, it always goes to its immediate child of type "other."

Comment: Could you ID your cells by getting the parent `otherElement` of those `staticText`s?

Answer (score 0):

There is a modifier in `SwiftUI` for that:

```
func accessibilityIdentifier(_ identifier: String) -> ModifiedContent<Self, AccessibilityAttachmentModifier>
```

if you add it to your `View` element like this:

```
.accessibility(identifier: ["MyCellIdentifier")
```

It will get exposed to `XCUITest`s

Comment: I forgot to mention that the same flags were moved over to the SwiftUI code. My issue is that even without using the flags in SwiftUI, generic queries like this one `let tableCells = app.table.cells` doesn't seem to work.